# Are vacuum energy, zero point energy and vacuum fluctuations the same thing?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, vacuum

im confused about the relationship between these terms, my intuition tells me that vacuum energy and zero point energy are synonymous and that they are a consequence of vacuum fluctuations. But I wouldn't be surprised if I'm completely wrong.
This within the context of quantum field theory.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology-wise, vacuum energy and zero-point energy are the same thing, though they are used in slightly different contexts. Zero-point energy applies to the residual energy of any quantum mechanical system in its lowest-energy state. Vacuum energy tends to refer specifically to the zero-point energy of a quantum field, like the electromagnetic field. See the [Wikipedia page on zero-point energy][1].

You are also correct that vacuum energy results from vacuum fluctuations. To justify this statement, consider the Hamiltonian (*i.e.* the energy) of a mass on a spring

$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + kx^2$

where the first term is the kinetic energy, the second term is the potential energy and $k$ is the spring constant. Quantum mechanically, the energy of this Hamiltonian is non-zero even in the ground state. This residual energy comes directly from $p^2$ and $x^2$ being non-zero. But $x$ and $p$ are both zero on average for the ground state, so $x^2 \neq 0$ and $p^2 \neq 0$ are only possible if the variance is non-zero. This non-zero variance is exactly the vacuum fluctuations.

Non-interacting quantum field theories are mathematically equivalent to an infinite collection of harmonic oscillators like the above, so the 'vacuum energy' still comes from vacuum fluctuations (or the equivalent version for fermions). For interacting field theories there can be other sources of energy. For example, a field can undergo spontaneous symmetry breaking and have non-zero average value. Now there is a contribution to the vacuum energy not just from fluctuations, but also from a net displacement of the field[2]. There can be much more complicated things going on in the ground states of interacting fields, like topological order.

[![Ground state wave functions for free and interacting fields][2]][2]

[1]: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy#:~:text=The%20vacuum%20can%20be%20viewed,called%20condensate%20or%20simply%20VEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy#:%7E:text=The%20vacuum%20can%20be%20viewed,called%20condensate%20or%20simply%20VEV)).
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VANWt.png

Answer (score 0):

Vacuum energy and zero-point energy are the same thing. Vacuum fluctuations, however, do not exist. The vacuum state is completely stationary in time. The concept of vacuum fluctuations is from the early days of quantum mechanics, when people tried to describe it using pictures from classical physics. It is unfortunate that it is still being used without a clearly defined meaning.

Comment: The term 'vacuum fluctuations' is still in common usage in the physics community, and and takes the meaning from the above answer. I agree that the word 'fluctuations' is a bit unfortunate, but it's incorrect to say that they don't exist.

Comment: @user34722 What fluctuates in the ground state? Nothing... so fluctuations *do not exist* in that case. You can put an $e^{-i\omega t}$ phase factor in front of it, if you don't define zero energy in the ground state, but even then the shape and other properties are constant, only that phase factor will rotate. (And the phase factor is not what the physics community means with the 'fluctuations' anyway! So they should just stop using the term and use for instance 'vacuum variance' or some other appropriate name.